# Espresso - Perform action fails on fullscreen activity - InjectEventSecurityException

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I wasted two days trying to perform click action on a fullscreen activity.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Create a new project in android studio using fullscreen activity code template
2. Write an espresso test for the activity to perform click

   ```
   public class FullscreenActivityTest 
                 extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<FullscreenActivity> {
   public FullscreenActivityTest() {
       super(FullscreenActivity.class);
   }

   @Override
   protected void setUp() throws Exception {
       super.setUp();
       getActivity();
   }

   public void testClickingOnLayout() {
       onView(withId(R.id.fullscreen_content)).perform(click());
   }
   ```

   }
3. Run this test on emulator (any android version from ginger bread to lollipop).

## Failure

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: 
Error performing 'click' on view 'with id: com.example.espressodefect:id/fullscreen_content'
...
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: 
Error performing 'Send down montion event' on view 'unknown'.
...
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: 
Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
```

Full stack is [here](https://gist.github.com/rpattabi/c8bff2e6556bbbeb65ad#file-espresso_fullscreen_click_error).

## Tried

I have tried the following with no luck:

- No lock screen on the emulator. (also updated activity using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)`
- All animations turned off
- No on-screen keyboard, or anything overlayed on top of the app.
- Also followed instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html) at developer.android.com
- JUnit3 and JUnit4 styles (AndroidJUnitRunner)
- `<uses-permission>` for INJECT_EVENTS

## TL;DR

In espresso test, performing actions work fine if I use non-fullscreen activity like the one created with blank activity. Same action on full screen fails.

I am using Espresso 2.0 and support libraries.

What am I doing wrong here?

## Update

Espresso dev confirmed this as defect. Please see [issue 140](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=140).

Comment: Could this be an espresso bug? I added a [defect](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=140) to see developer's response.

Comment: I was running into this occasionally too. I think what I did to "solve" it was add a sleep call just before the `perform(click())`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @CarlAnderson It does not seem like espresso is having synchronization problem here. So adding a delay did not help here. I tried delays of different length.

Comment: Response from espresso team: "We can investigate further, but my first reaction to seeing the error is that it might be impossible to do anything in this case."

Comment: Yeah, I have not been very impressed with the framework.

Comment: I feel it has good potential. Also, I don't find decent white box testing alternatives for UI.

Comment: Oh, it is useful for some testing, but I've started running into it's limitations, and for something that has a reputation as being "the best", it leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: I see your point. It has become part of android AOSP. Hopefully it improves faster. I am curious, once you hit a road block with espresso, how do you make progress in your app?

Comment: The biggest problem I've had with it right now is when my test needs to leave the UI to do something - Facebook login, choose photo from the Photo gallery, etc. Espresso does not support this. I tried hacking it, starting tests from after login after doing a fake login, for instance, and it just does not make the tests easy to write. I eventually gave up on testing those aspects and rely on manual testing instead for now.

Comment: The examples you point out belong to end-to-end tests, not in UI tests as I learned recently [here](http://googletesting.blogspot.in/2015/03/android-ui-automated-testing.html?m=1). This google testing blog post recommends us to use fake external dependencies (like you tried) for UI tests to reduce flakiness. Integration tests (using android instrumentation) could be used for testing with external dependencies (and without GUI). Not sure how this works in practice, though.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a lot to think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was solved in the last release of Espresso:

Espresso 2.2.2, Runner/Rules 0.5 (2016-02-22, silent release) - https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/release-notes/index.html

In my project, i've changed the dependency in the /app/build.grandle from:

*androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'*

to

*androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'*

**In AndroidStudio: Grandle Scripts => build.gradle file**

Comment: It still happens for us, using 2.2.2

Comment: @dweebo i've struggling with this issue on May in a Mac OSX configuration computer. I have the project in Github : https://github.com/tiagomestreteixeira/HKUSTx-COMP107x-Introduction-to-Mobile-Application-Development-using-Android/tree/master/GreetFriend

Comment: I've forgot to mention that it still passes my 8 unit tests. They're basically do the following:      

`onView(withId(R.id.editFriendName)).perform(typeText("John"), closeSoftKeyboard()); 
  



onView(withId(R.id.greetButton)).perform(click());        



onView(withId(R.id.textMessage)).check(matches(withText(String.format("%s John!", greetMessage))));`

Sorry for the bad formatting